# Is it possible to construct a closed, simple curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that has a segment with zero curvature and is differentiable everywhere?

Tags: geometry, plane-curves

The question title says it all.  Presume I am interested in creating a closed, simple curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contains a segment with zero curvature (that is, part of it is a straight line).  This segment must have finite length.  I am now interested in whether or not it is possible to create a closed, simple curve with such a segment that is also differentiable.  Since a curve made up of only line segments (a polygon) would not be differentiable at the vertices, I expect that such a curve would be made of nonlinear curves stitched in somehow so that the derivatives are equal at the stitching points, perhaps?  I'm not sure how to proceed to create such a curve, or what it might look like.

Comment: Use a "mump function": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: I'm not sure whether you would allow this (because at certain points the tangent line is vertical), but if you take a circle, cut it at the top and bottom points so that you have two half circles, move them apart a bit, and join them back together with straight lines then you get such a curve.

Comment: @James: that is perfect, thank you.  Please write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @kimchilover: I like your suggestion as well, but I'm not sure how to close a bump function to satisfy the differentiability example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the left half of the circle radius $1$ centered at the origin, and the right half of the circle radius $1$ centered at $(1,0)$ and add to these the line segments from $(0,-1)$ to $(1,-1)$ and $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$, i.e., join the two half circles together.